# Solve for x & y for this complex equation.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$(2+3i)x² - (3-2i)y = 2x - 3y + 5i$

Where "i" is $\sqrt-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two complex numbers are equal if and only if the real parts are equal and the imaginary parts are also equal.

In your problem we have $$ 2x^2 -3y = 2x-3y$$ and $$ 3x^2+2y =5$$.

solve for $x$ and $y$ to get $$ x=0, y=5/2$$ or $$x=1, y=1$$

Comment: You are assuming $x,y$ are real, which is probably correct but not given by OP